# vhost wamp - codeigniter - I have m.localhost, I want *.m.localhost go to m.localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp, virtualhost

I have `m.localhost` working fine. I want all `*.m.localhost` load files from `m.localhost`.

```
x.m.localhost -> m.localhost

y.m.localhost -> m.localhost
```

I’m using codeigniter, and code will show info depending on `x` or `y`.

Comment: Just use `ServerAlias` with a wildcard …

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about what probelm you are trying to solve please. Currently not sure exactly what what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Setup new default site in your server config,
Setup proper htaccess to load files from your m.localhost directory using rewrite url.